# Should I always complete a TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, taskcompletionsource

What happens to a `TaskCompletionSource` and its `Task` if the `TaskCompletionSource` is never completed (i.e. `SetCancelled`, `SetException` or `SetResult`is never called? Would the `Task` live on forever because it never completes?

In the below example I have a simplified version of a parameterized test. In case of a timeout (`MyEevent` is not called within 1000ms) the `TaskCompletionSource` (`tcs`) is never completed. I have a lot of tests like this. Do I need to do any sort of cleanup (e.g. make sure tcs.SetCancelled() is called).?

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("aa")]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(true)]
[InlineData(null)]
public async Task RaiseMyEvent_RaisesMyEvent_WithOriginalValue(object value)
{
    var sut = new Thing();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    sut.MyEvent += (_, args) => tcs.SetResult(args.Value);

    sut.RaiseMyEvent(value);

    tcs.Task.Should().BeSameAs(await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(1000), tcs.Task), "MyEvent should be raised within 1000ms");
    tcs.Task.Result.Should().Be(value);
}
```

While we are at it, is there any way I could improve the above test (e.g. make it even more concise/simple/readable)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need to do any sort of cleanup (e.g. make sure `tcs.SetCancelled()` is called)?

Using a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` doesn't require any cleanup. In fact, it doesn't even admit any cleanup. So the answer to your question is "no."

The `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is just a conceptually simple data structure that allows you to push in *at most* a single thing (a result of type `T`, an exception, or a cancellation). Its `Task` property exposes a `Task<T>` that is just a wrapper around this promised single thing that will be pushed into the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` at some time in the future.  It does not use the task pool whatsoever.

To never push anything into a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is perfectly valid.  This just corresponds to a `Task<T>` that will "run" forever and never complete.